# Create b2c user to sign in with username from graph calls

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-authentication, azure-rest-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create b2c user to sign in only with their user name without entering email address using Microsoft Graph calls.

Usually I use below graph call to create users in normal tenant:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": " ",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "password": "password-value",
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

I want these users to sign in only with their user name.
Is their any approach to get these from graph calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

To create b2c user to sign in only with their **username** without entering email address, you need to add identities with  **`"signInType": "userName"`** in your query like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "Sri Devi",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userName",
      "issuer": "yourb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "username_of_user"
    }
  ],
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "password": "password-value",
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, you can check the same in Portal as below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Switch to your B2C tenant -> Azure AD  B2C -> Users -> All users***

[image]

Make sure to give your B2C **domain name** as **`issuer`** value that you can find here:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Switch to your B2C tenant -> Azure AD  B2C***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS) to see the list of available auth flow and you can choose authentication provider based on your scenario.

Hope this helps,

Thanks